# How to map missing values of a df's column according to another column's values (of the same df) using a dictionary? Python

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I managed to solve using if and for loops but I'm looking for a less computationally expensive way to do this. i.e. using apply or map or any other technique

```
d = {1:10, 2:20, 3:30}

df

a    b
1    35
1    nan
1    nan
2    nan
2    47
2    nan
3    56
3    nan
```

I want to fill missing values of column b according to dict d, i.e. output should be

```
a    b
1    35
1    10
1    10
2    20
2    47
2    20
3    56
3    30
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of your code, but post actual code. I have made the appropriate edit to your post.

Comment: thanks man, I've been trying to figure out how to do this for like an hour, this is my first question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) or [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) by [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html)ed `a` column:

```
print (df['a'].map(d))
0    10
1    10
2    10
3    20
4    20
5    20
6    30
7    30
Name: a, dtype: int64

df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(df['a'].map(d))
print (df)
   a     b
0  1  35.0
1  1  10.0
2  1  10.0
3  2  20.0
4  2  47.0
5  2  20.0
6  3  56.0
7  3  30.0
```

---

```
df['b'] = df['b'].combine_first(df['a'].map(d))
print (df)
   a     b
0  1  35.0
1  1  10.0
2  1  10.0
3  2  20.0
4  2  47.0
5  2  20.0
6  3  56.0
7  3  30.0
```

And if all values are `int`s add [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(df['a'].map(d)).astype(int)
print (df)
   a   b
0  1  35
1  1  10
2  1  10
3  2  20
4  2  47
5  2  20
6  3  56
7  3  30
```

If all data in column `a` are in keys of dict, then is possible use `replace`:

```
df['b'] = df['b'].fillna(df['a'].replace(d))
```

Comment: Nice answer @jezrael! Definitely more sophisticated than mine, +1 ! Just one question, I get 25% speed increase when using ```.replace(to_replace=d))``` instead of ```.map(d)```. Do you have a similar experience?

Comment: @Daan Thank you. I am thinking about replace too, but I think in this situtation it is problem. Because if use `d = {1:10, 2:20}`  then after replace NaNs for key 3 are replaced by 3. But it can be NaN. But it depends of data if all keys are same with unique values of a column, then replace can be used. Good luck!